# DBVisualizer: how to increase fetch size?

Tags: oracle, fetch, dbvisualizer

I want to increase the fetch size in DbVisualizer on an Oracle DB.

The standard fetch size is by 100 rows per time, not more, and this is not enough for very large amounts of data (for example during @export operations) because it needs too much time.

So, how can I increase the value of the fetch size in DbVisualizer settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained in [this](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Configuring+Connection+Properties#ConfiguringConnectionProperties-InvokeJavamethodsintheJDBCdriver) link.

We need to override the `java.sql.statement.setFetchSize` property in the Driver Properties of the SQL Connection.

Steps to do:

Right click on the SQL Connection -> Edit Database Connection(s)... -> choose tab Properties -> select Driver Properties in the list -> clic on the "+" icon -> add the `java.sql.statement.setFetchSize` property with the custom value

Example:

```
java.sql.statement.setFetchSize    25000
```

In this way, you can increase the performance of the SQL operations.